# How to produce null field using select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the query specified below.

```
  Select distinct a.Item_Name, b.Item_Rate, b.professional_Charge, c.discount , c.discount_Type,
 a.Dept_ID, c.Discount_Applicability
 From Item_M a
 left outer join Rate_M  b on a.Item_Code = b.Bill_Item 
 left outer join Discount_M c on a.Item_Code = c.Item_Code
 Where a.Item_code = 'ABS002' and b.Rate_Cat_ID = 'DLX' and
  c. Pay_Type_Id='BD'
```

Below output suggest that for item_Code ‘ABS002’ Rate cat_id is’DLX’ and Pay_type_Id is ‘BD’.

```
item_name item_rate professinal_charge discount discount_type DEPT_ID  Discount_Applicability  

 ABSESS I&D  440      NULL               0                P       CBN     1
```

Let us assume that item_code `ABS002` doesn’t contain the `Rate_cat_Id` and `Pay_type _ID` then the ouput will be only the headers will be displayed but no the values.That will be a perfect query execution.But for my requirement if the above condition arises I need the output look like.

```
  item_name item_rate professinal_charge discount discount_type DEPT_ID  Discount_Applicability  

 ABSESS I&D  NULL      NULL               NULL                NULL       NULL     NULL
```

The only time the headers should be displayed when the item_code is not present in the item_m table
Any help appreciated

Comment: Does it work if you change your `where` clause to `where a.Item_code = 'ABS002' and (b.Rate_Cat_ID is null or b.Rate_Cat_ID = 'DLX') and (c.Pay_Type_Id is null or c. Pay_Type_Id='BD')`?

Comment: @BenM No it doesnt work :(

Comment: What if you move the b and c conditions from the WHERE into their respective ON clauses?